# Number of tables in a tablespace in db2

Tags: db2, mainframe

I tried getting the number of tables of a particular tablespace and database from SYSIBM.SYSTABLES using the select query. This number is more than the number of tables for the same tablespace and database stored in the SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACE table under the NTABLES column. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *could* be the fact that `systables` stores entries for each table, view or alias, in fact a large number of objects that may not necessarily be included within a tablespace.

You could confirm this by only listing those where `type = 'T'` (or some other combination of the allowed values).

If you select `count(*)` from `systables` (for a given tablespace) and group it by `type`, you may find it reasonably easy to assign some of those types to the tablespace.

Comment: Nice! The only thing is, now I'm getting one table more in the `NTABLES` as compared to `SYSTABLES` with `type='T'`